# How to Print logo with bill receipt?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, streamwriter

I'm working Windows Application and C#, my application based on restaurant billing process. when i generate the bill its print with logo.
Now, its only print text format.

We are using our application its write all text information through stream writer from notepad file.

This is my sample code,

```
string strTextFileName = "ESC" + "1" + ".txt";
        string strTextFilePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + strTextFileName;

        if (File.Exists(strTextFilePath))
            File.Delete(strTextFilePath);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strTextFilePath))
        {

            sw.WriteLine("---------------------");
            sw.WriteLine("start s for testing of the Print in t end");
        }
```

Please anyone help to me.

Comment: Have you ever seen a logo in a `.txt` file which you open in notepad? `.txt` file only contains text.

Comment: .txt file only support text . you use generate pdf file

Comment: have to give some sample project

Comment: better to use pdf and put logo and text in it.